# select row based on what a substring in a column might contain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to select the primary key of a row and I've only got a column that contains info (in a substring) that I need to select the row.

E.g. MyTable

---

```
ID | Label

------------
11 | 1593:#:#:RE: test
12 | 1239#:#:#some more random text
13 | 12415#:#:#some more random text about the weather
14 | 369#:#:#some more random text about the StackOverflow
```

The label column has *always* a delimiter of *:#:#:*

So really I guess,  I'd need to be able to split this row by the delimiter, grab the first part of the label column (i.e. the number I'm looking) to get the id I wanted.

So, If I wanted row with ID of 14, then I'd be:

```
Select ID from MyTable 
where *something* = '369'
```

Any ideas on how to construct *something* ..or how best to go about this:)

I'm completely stumped and haven't been able to find how to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Ah yes, that would do. D'oh! I was over thinking this.

Comment: Add it as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE label LIKE '369#%'?
```

No reason to get fancy.

Although.. if you are going to do this search often, then maybe pre-split that value out to another column as part of your ETL process and index it.

Comment: Do'h, yep, cheers. It's only to delete a row which won't happen very often.